# Co-ordinates of a vector in relation to the basis

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Find the co-ordinates of the vector $u = (2,-1,4)$ of $\mathbb R^3$ in relation the basis
$S = \{(1,1,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,0)\}$.

Please could someone help/explain this to me, I'm doing revision for my exam which is soon and came along this question we haven't studied. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Solve

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 
b\\ 
c
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
2\\
-1\\ 
4
\end{bmatrix}

I think?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a matrix equation
$$
    S = A \,[i\,j \,k] 
$$
where $i$, $j$, $k$ are matrix column that represent the basis of $\mathbb{R}^3_{}$. The above equation is multiplication of a matrix $A$ which has the dimension equals $3 \times 3$ with a matrix $[i\,j\,k]$ which has the dimension equals $3 \times 3$.